# Delete 2 model different objects which reference each other as foreign keys

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, foreign-keys

We have two Django models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

class User(models.Model):
    usernmae = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    active_project = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='current_project')
```

I have a user with object (with `id` say `692`). And this user created a project with `id=12345`, therefore these `owner` field will get have this particular referenced.
I want to delete that user. But it shows error that

```
delete on table "app_user" violates foreign key constraint
```

This is expected as `on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING`, was set. One way I found out was using `on_delete=models.CASCADE`.

Question: How should I go about deleting the user (`692`) without changing the model definition(having to re-run migration)?
Doing it manually by deleting the project first, leads to the same `foreign-key` error, as `owner` field is `User` object.
How to handle this mutual foreign key relationship while deleting, as deleting any one of those two throws the foreign-key exception?

**Update**
Some correction in the model definition `username` is the field name instead of `usernmae` (typo). And the foreignkey for project is `Project` not the `User` model.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    active_project = models.ForeignKey(Project, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='current_project')
```

Comment: Probably the best way is to do this in a transaction. An alternative might be to first set one of the two `ForeignKey`s to `NULL`.

Comment: In class `USER` is it really `usernmae` not `username`? More importantly why does `active_project` have a FK on `User` not `Project`? Add answers as update to your question.

Answer (score 0):

IF you really don't want to make a migration (any specific reason?) and if you  are ok with doing this manually this time. Then you have two options:

1. Go into the admin panel and manually change the `User` field in the `project` instance to a different user or to NULL. Now you should be able to delete the `User` instance since it's not referred anymore into the project.
2. If that worked, you can then delete the project instane as well.

Curios if this will work, let me know!